# Removed Old Domain Trust. Now Progress (9.1D) can't open DB File

Tags: database

My company has an old server, running Progress 9.1D on a Windows 2000 VM, which was used by our company OS (Vantage 6 by Epicor.) Vantage was our primary OS for a very long time. About 2 years ago, we migrated to a larger, corporate OS and we cancelled our service contract with Epicor.

Yesterday, we removed an AD trust between the corporate domain and our old AD domain we used in the days of Vantage. After restarting the virtual server, I have been able to start the *ProService for 9.1D* Windows service, however, I can not get Vantage to start back up. When I run the application, I get the error in the message listed below.

Transcript:

```
** Could not connect to server for database [progress db file], errno 0. (1432)
```

How can I fix this? FYI, I haven't had to work with Progress in years and even then I wouldn't have considered myself a "novice"-- I'm even less knowledgeable than that title would suggest.

Vantage had a lot of internal tools and I recall that Epicor support managed to prevent .pf scripts from being executed. If there was a Progress specific patch that needed to be applied, you had to do it within the Vantage software OR they had to remote into the machine to fix this.

I may not be able to run a .pf script but I do know that I can log into the console-based server application. (Yes, I can't even recall which utility that was called. It is sad.) It's been a long time and I never had to digg into Progress that much.

Please help and feel free to ask questions.  If you need more info, I'll update this post.

Comment: FYI, I was speaking in chat with some of the guys at DBA.  They tend to think that since this is permissions/software related, it might belong here.

Comment: Do you know if Vantage use a native connection, or an ODBC connection?

Comment: @Tim Kuehn: It's a native connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the database you're trying to connect to is running -

if Vantage is using a client-server connection, then the database needs to be started with a "-S" parameter which specifies a service port name or number the db engine will listen on for connections. This can be found in either a ".pf" file, or on the script which starts the database.  You can find the value it's using by looking in the .lg file and searching for the last "-S" setting.

If Vantage is attempting to connect to the correct port, then you need to check your firewall settings to see if it is allowing Vantage to access that port, and the database has permissions to listen on that port.

The startup command could look like:

```
mpro db-name -H hostname -S portname-or-number -p program.p
```

also -

```
mpro -pf pfname.pf
```

is a way to hide the startup complexity in a .pf file.

IF vantage wants to use a self-serve connection (ie, not client-server) then the startup command needs to look something like this:

```
mpro /full/path/to/db/db-name -p programname.p
```

If you can get to an 4GL client editor, the ABL code to connect to a database looks like this for client-server connection:

```
 CONNECT VALUE("db-name -H hostname -S portname-or-number").
```

and this for self-serve connection:

```
CONNECT VALUE("/full/path/to/db/db-name").
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. Vantage doesn't quite work that way.  However, Vantage does certainly need a specific port open to connect to Progress.  In this case, our db port is 6010. It is open and has been used for a long time.  Vantage doesn't appear to us a `.p` or `.pf` file to connect.  Instead, it has `.mfg` files with various settings in it.  I think it takes information from that file and constructs a connection string based off the info stored in the `.mfg` file.  How can I change which Windows/AD account starts/stops/admins our DB for Vantage?

Comment: .p are program files
.pf are typical startup parameter files, although other extensions (like .mfg) could be used. If the startup command is -pf xyz.mfg, then the "mfg" is being used the same way a .pf is.

In terms of changing the account which starts / stops the db, etc. - I _think_ you'd need to look under your services admin to control that. I'm not a windows guy so I can't say for sure though.

Comment: Ugh. Thank you for your response, but I'm back at square one.  The Progress services are working fine and can be start/stopped by their associated account.  There is a breakdown, however, some where between the Vantage application and Progress.  I assumed this was a Progress issue, because both the error message and the associated dialog appear to be from Progress.  Would you happen to possibly know a Window Progress guru?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Giving you the answer mark since this was the closest help.

Comment: What was the root problem?

Comment: Sorry, I had to give up this issue.  We reverted a few things and another tech took over the project.  I'll be honest.  I'm not in IT any more and IT for our company keeps coming to me for help on stuff like this.  When I get a chance to pass this stuff off, I try to as much as I can.  I have embedded systems work I'd rather be doing.